# How to access the geojson file correctly?

Tags: python, pandas, geojson, folium

I want to use folium and GeoJSON file to map data on the world map.
Therefore I have to access the GeoJSON file correctly. But I haven't figured out how.

```
KeyError: "None of [Index(['STATE_CODE', 'STATE_NAME'], dtype='object', name='Province')] are in the [index]"
```

Index is from the data_AU_series (pd.Series)

STATE_NAME is in the geoJSON file and has to be accessed and act as key for the Series to get the date.

**geodata_australia** from a GeoJSON file:

```
{'type': 'FeatureCollection',
 'features': [{'type': 'Feature',
   'id': 0,
   'properties': {'STATE_CODE': '1', 'STATE_NAME': 'New South Wales'},
   'geometry': {'type': 'MultiPolygon',
    'coordinates': [[[[159.10542, -31.563994],
       [159.09775, -31.564275],
       [159.099634, -31.573372],...
```

**data_AU_series** (the data (pd.Series) I want to display on the map):

```
Province
Victoria                       2020-03-24
...
```

The line of code I wanted to assign the value from the series to the geodata and color

**folium**

```
folium.GeoJson(
    geodata_australia,
    name='data_AU',
    style_function=lambda feature: {
        'fillColor': colormap(data_AU_series[feature['properties']]),
        'color': 'black',
        'weight': 1,
        'dashArray': '5, 5',
        'fillOpacity': 0.9,
    }
).add_to(m)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works with a second key ['STATE_NAME']

```
colormap(data_AU_series[feature['properties']['STATE_NAME']]
```